# Typescript index signature with an exception not working for array

Tags: javascript, typescript

For the following code

```
❌ let b:({[key:string]:string} & {test:number})[] = [{yes:"yes", test:3}];
```

Why does the definition `b` show an error?

```
Type '{ yes: string; test: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; } & { test: number; }'.
  Type '{ yes: string; test: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
    Property 'test' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: For me `a` doesn't work as well. Shouldn't it be `|` instead of `&`? `&` is common part of the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `&` with `|` fixes the issue for me

```
let a:{[key:string]:string} | {test:number} = {yes:"yes", test:3}; 
let b:({[key:string]:string} | {test:number})[] = [{yes:"yes", test:3}];
```

`&` takes the common part of the two types, but there is no common part of `{[key:string]:string}` and `{test:number}`

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXA3gbQNYgJ4wM5gE4EsB2A5gLqY4GEC+EAPhHGCFjPgK4C2ARiNtQLz1UTGACIhGEQBoIjZgGZKAbggAoUJE4wAFIhToseIqQMVqdBkzAsO3XgEoExCAIRxxo8VJmWYC4sqA)

Comment: but why does it work for `a` but not `b`?

Comment: @Abraham code in the question doesn't `work` for `a` https://imgur.com/a/QfiDgY3

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to make both `yes` and `test` required? using `|` it makes it possible to assign only `{yes:"yes"}`

Answer (score 0):

`TypeScript` becomes more strict when using index signatures with intersection types in arrays.

When dealing with complex types, `TypeScript` tries to ensure that the types are as accurate and safe as possible. This strictness can sometimes lead to scenarios where certain type combinations seem to work in isolation but not in more complex structures, such as arrays or objects. And this is your use case.